# AngularJS translate & ui tooltip html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-translate

I have such view:

```
uib-tooltip-html="tooltipData(form, field)"
```

and `tooltipData` returns data (example):

```
***
var str = $translate.instant('LONG_EMAIL')
return str;
***
```

and when i switch lang of my app - translation isn't updating((

when i hardcode (it's a bad way of solving this issue)

```
uib-tooltip-html="{{'LONG_EMAIL' | translate}}"
```

all is fine

How can i translate my string returned from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by having `$filter` over `translate`

```
var str = $filter('translate')('LONG_EMAIL')
return str;
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution

`uib-tooltip="{{ 'LONG_EMAIL' | translate }}"`